# tx_news Paginate with dynamic variables

Tags: typo3, fluid, tx-news

I have created a custom template for paginations. But I want to display a count of all news articels and so I'm looking for a solution to pass a variables to the pagination. I don't want to build a custom viewhelper, I want to stick with the original PagionationViewhelper.

Maybe have anyone a idea?

Answer (score 1):

Make the counting with a cObject like lib.newscount 
then you pass that with the cObject Viewhelper like:

```
<f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.newscount"></f:cObject>
```

Comment: A nice idea! But i have try it and it isn't functional.
I want to copy my TS here in this field...but it is not formated :/

I have try it - but it isn't functional.
Here my TypoScript. 

[code]
lib.newsNewsTotalCount = TEXT
lib.newsNewsTotalCount {
 
 table = tx_news_domain_model_news_category_mm
 select{
  selectFields = count(uid) AS count
  where = deleted=0 AND uid_foreign=4
 }
 
 renderObj = COA
 renderObj{
  10 = TEXT
  10{
   data = field:count
  }
 }
}
[/code]

Comment: Please post this as a news question. I cannot read anything. If your basic question was answered, please mark it as answered.